# How to add pre-existing multiple .exe files in a installer using WiX?

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.10

I am new to WiX. I have multiple .exe files supplied by different vendors. I need to combine them together with one more application(.exe) developed by me. I used WiX for my application and created a installer for it (installs developed exe file).

How can I add the pre-existing .exe files into the same installer package so that the resulting package would install all the .exe files along with developed .exe file. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show us your current Wix code?

Comment: You need to make use of WiX Bundle:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/

Comment: @Girish, Do you want to install or only deploy (copy) those exe to traget system ?

Comment: @AjitMedhekar I want to install, I figured it out by using Bootstrapper in WiX. However, I was not able to combine Wix Installer project and Bootstrapper project into one single standalone project. You have any idea on it?

Comment: No you can not combine both projects,  as they are the different projects. But You can create a Bootstrapper project & add/refer your WiX installer project's MSI to it